My Python-pytest-selenium project logger generates the logs in a file successfully but the pytest html report is not generated
I am a newbie to pytest as well as pytest-html. I've tried to search an answer for this question on the StackOverFlow as well as on the Internet in general but couldn't find a solution.
I have Python 3.11.5 on my Windows 10 OS. My Python-selenium-pytest Eclipse-based-project is located on D driver whereas my OS is on C drive, Python installed on C:\Py3.11.
I have created PYTHONPATH environment variable and added the path to Python 3.11 as well as the path to my pytest project.
I have created a simple pytest file and used the standard python Logger which I have defined in the testcases' parent class in a different file in a different folder. I am using 'logger_obj.info()' whereas I have set 'self.proj_logger.level = logging.DEBUG'.
I execute my tests from cmd line as "py.test --html=report.html". After test completion, I can see the logs I am trying to generate in my .log text file but the html report doesn't show these logs. I am attaching some snapshots below to help visualize my issue:


What am I missing?
